# Drawing Individual Pixels in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to highlight ("color #00FFFF") specific individual pixels in an image (already displayed in the background) using OpenGL/C++.  The pixel coordinates and the image exist in exact 2D space, but all the OpenGL code I'm seeing in the project so far - `glTranslatef()`, `glScalef()` - is 3D and float-based, and the positioning of the object appears to happen separately from the time it's drawn.

I'm used to Java's Graphics2D package, where I can call something to the effect of

```
width = 1; height = 1;
buffer.drawRect(width, height, xPosition, yPosition);
```

and it'll fill in a pixel at the specified location.  Is there anything similar to that syntax - where I can set size, set position, and draw all in one line - in OpenGL?  If not, how would I go about adapting my 2D+pixel input to OpenGL's float and 3D structure?

I currently have this:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
glPointSize(5.0f);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glPopMatrix();
```

which I pieced together from some Google searches and other parts of my code, but I don't see anything being draw.  I have no idea as to the units for the translate, vertex, or pointsize commands.  It'd be awesome if I could replace all of that with something like the Java command up above.  If not, is there some way I can guarantee whatever I draw here will be "on top" of everything else, but still not behind the camera.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? OpenGL is a 3D vector library by design so I would look on something else (painting by single pixels from CPU side would be terribly inefficient to put it mildly if you want to get 3D graphics) - I would look on 2D bitmal vector library. In worst case you might want to look on textures although it is sub-optimal solution. (Also - you are using deprecated version of OpenGL).

Comment: I'm trying to debug some computer vision stuff, so I'd like to overlay some bright pixels on top of the parts of the camera feed that have been selected.
I assume you mean "2D bitma*p* vector lib"?  That sounds better; how would I go about doing... that?  (I don't have any experience with C++ or OpenGL, so I didn't know what's used for what).

Comment: Yes (I have no way to correct it now). Well - for one you need to choose one. Depending on your requirements you may use say cairo (I don't know platform you need it on etc.). For debugging you may go with this solution but my filling is that you have not chosen the best tools (OpenGL deals with 3D vector graphic accelerators while you want 2D pixmaps). You may want to scratch the depractaion notice (OpenGL 1.x is more beginner-user-friendly but the friendliness cames at too greate cost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything similar to that syntax - where I can set size, set position, and draw all in one line - in OpenGL?

[`glRect()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRect.xml):

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
    glEnable( GL_CULL_FACE );
    glEnable( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE );

    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );

    glDepthMask( GL_TRUE );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    // draw teapot
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glDepthMask( GL_TRUE );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 60, w / h, 1, 100 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -5 );

    glColor4ub( 255, 0, 0, 255 );
    glPushMatrix(); 
    float angle = 60.0f * ( glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0f );
    glRotatef( angle, 0.1, 0.95, 0.05 );
    glutSolidTeapot( 1.0 );
    glPopMatrix();

    // draw rectangle
    glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glDepthMask( GL_FALSE );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0, w, 0, h, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor4ub( 0, 255, 0, 128 );
    glRecti( 0 + 50, 0 + 50, w - 50, h - 50 );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer( int extra )
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Rect" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```